# Spring JPA and form filter

Tags: java, spring, forms, jpa, controller

I have a web page with a search form (with *name* and *surname* fields) and a table of persons. When user inserts a *name* `n` and a *surname* `s` I have to show the persons with *name* like `n` **and** *surname* like `s`. When user inserts only the *name* I have to filter only by *name* and the same when user inserts only the *surname*.

My `searchPersons` method in *Controller* looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RouteConfig.SEARCH_PERSONS)    
public @ResponseBody Page<Person> searchPersons(@ModelAttribute Person p, Pageable pageable) {
    return pazienteRepository.findAll(where(nameIsLike(p.getName())).and(surnameIsLike(p.getSurname())), pageable);
}
```

I write a `PersonSpecifications` class:

```
public class PersonSpecifications {

    public static Specification<Person> nomeIsLike(String name) {
        return (Root<Person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> 
                cb.like(cb.lower(root.<String>get(Person_.nome)), getLikePattern(name));
    }

    public static Specification<Person> surnameIsLike(String surname) {
        return (Root<Person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) ->
             cb.like(cb.lower(root.<String>get(Person_.surname)), getLikePattern(surname));
    }
```

Now if I have *name* and *surname* my search is ok. The problem is when *name* or *surname* is not valued in the web form.

What's the best practice in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can just put a check for name and surname both having values, in your searchPersons method. If `name != null`, add name condition, if `surname != null` add surname condition. As long as 1 condition was added, execute query.